# How to do If Error If Vlookup with validations in vba macros

Tags: vba, vlookup

I need to do a macro with this formula.

```
=SI.ERROR(SI(A2=BUSCARV(A2;'NOVEDAD CARTOLA'!$A$2:$A$938965;1);C2;"No Cargar");"Error"
```

Wich returns C2 if it matches, it throws me "1004" error marking the formula.

I've tried this:

```
Sub Buscar()

Dim lr As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BASE")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("D2:D" & lr).Formula = "=SI.ERROR(SI(A2=BUSCARV(A2;'NOVEDAD CARTOLA'!$A$2:$A$938965;1);C2; 'No Cargar'); 'Error')"
End With

End Sub
```

And is important to return the result validated (If matches: return column C, If doesn't: a String, If error: String Error) in column D

Comment: `.formula` wants the formula in EN-US format.  Use `.FormulaLocal`

Comment: It still throwing error 1004

Comment: `"=SI.ERROR(SI(A2=BUSCARV(A2;'NOVEDAD CARTOLA'!$A$2:$A$938965;1);C2; ""No Cargar""); ""Error"")"`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked!!